# Why does the golang nacl box and sign packages use different key lengths?

Tags: go, cryptography

[The box package generates keys of 32 length](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto/nacl/box#GenerateKey) and the [sign package generates keys of 64 length](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto/nacl/sign#GenerateKey)

This requires me to manage two sets of keys. Just curious why this is the case?

Comment: The 64 bytes secret key is the concatenation of the 32 bytes secret key and the 32 bytes public key, s. also [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/54353).

Comment: about `This requires me to manage two sets of keys` https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/quickstart#do-i-need-to-add-a-signature-to-encrypted-messages-to-detect-if-they-have-been-tampered-with